# How to create a time spiral graph with an origin farther from the center and with a radius greater than 0 using matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am relatively new to graphing with matplotlib, currently I am trying to graph a time range spiral I have been working for days and I am having a problem that I have not been able to solve.

I am graphing from an excel file with the following format in 1 minute intervals, I have data of up to 30 days.

```
 
Timestamp       alarms summatory
01/12/2018 00:00        3
01/12/2018 00:01        1
01/12/2018 00:02        2
01/12/2018 00:03        1
01/12/2018 00:04        1
01/12/2018 00:05        3
01/12/2018 00:06        1
01/12/2018 00:07        3
01/12/2018 00:08        1
01/12/2018 00:09        4
01/12/2018 00:10        3
```

Supporting myself from other questions asked in this community and a little documentation, I have obtained the following graph where 2 pi is a day and each color represents the number of alarms that have been activated for one minute:

[Mygraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alE4D.png)

I would like to show these events of 1 minute but in a way in which their visualization is easier from the first day as the following graph which has an empty center and the line begins to draw farther from the center :

[Graph Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jmuR.jpg)

I have been trying to modify parameters of the linespace function to try to get the graph of the last image but none has worked and I don't know what else to do, I hope someone can help me.

this is the code that I have been using and excel file.

[Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XEOmamGcu_ahaFVqCUN1DGHW92gdaAjU/view?usp=sharing)

Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as mpe
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# styling 
LINEWIDTH=5
EDGEWIDTH=0
CAPSTYLE="projecting"
ALPHA=1
FIRSTHOUR=0 # 0= 24 hrs, 23= 23 hrs

cdict = {'red':  ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
(1/6., 0.0, 0.0),
(1/2., 0.8, 1.0),
(5/6., 1.0, 1.0),
(1.0, 0.4, 1.0)),
'green':  ((0.0, 0.0, 0.4),
(1/6., 1.0, 1.0),
(1/2., 1.0, 0.8),
(5/6., 0.0, 0.0),
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
'blue': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
(1/6., 0.0, 0.0),
(1/2., 0.9, 0.9),
(5/6., 0.0, 0.0),
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
}

COLORMAP=colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["green","yellow","red"])
#Read excel
df = pd.read_excel('alarms_boiler_1min_v2.xlsx')
df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].replace('/','-').apply(pd.to_datetime)

#set origin  
firts_timestamp =df['Timestamp'].min()
origin = (firts_timestamp + pd.to_timedelta(firts_timestamp.hour - FIRSTHOUR, unit='hours'))
day = pd.date_range("00:00", "23:00", freq="60min").strftime('%H:%M').tolist()
# convert alarms sumatory timestamps to day fractions
df['start'] = (df['Timestamp'] - origin) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
df['stop'] = (pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Timestamp']) + timedelta(minutes=1)- origin)/np.timedelta64(1, 
'D')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.gca(projection="polar")

for idx, event in df.iterrows():
    # sample normalized alarms summatory colormap
    alarms_sum = event['alarms summatory']/4        
    color = plt.cm.get_cmap(COLORMAP)(alarms_sum)
    tstart, tstop = event.loc[['start', 'stop']]
    # timestamps are in day fractions, 2pi is one day
    nsamples = int(10000. * (tstop - tstart))
    t = np.linspace(tstart, (tstop),nsamples)
    theta = 2 * np.pi * (t) 
    arc, = ax.plot(theta, t, lw=LINEWIDTH, color=color, solid_capstyle=CAPSTYLE, alpha=ALPHA)
    arc.set_path_effects([mpe.Stroke(linewidth=LINEWIDTH+EDGEWIDTH, foreground='black'),mpe.Normal()])

#set grid, labels
ax.set_rticks([])
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 24, endpoint=False))
ax.set_xticklabels(day)
ax.tick_params('x', pad=2)
ax.grid(True)
#show graph
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=4)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=COLORMAP, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])
plt.colorbar(sm, ticks=np.linspace(0, 4, 10), fraction=0.04, aspect=60, pad=0.1, label="alarms summatory", ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much in advance and good day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to SO! A very nice first question.

You can convert a polar plot to a "donut" plot pretty easily by setting negative y/r-limits:

```
ax.set_rlim(bottom=-10) # or ax.set_ylim(bottom=-10)
```

[image]